# Is there a function that changes a global variable given by the parameters in JS?

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to make a button that changes a global variable.

HTML

```
<script src='script.js'><script>
<button onclick = "myFunction(a)>Increase A</button>
<button onclick = "myFunction(b)>Increase B</button>
```

JavaScript

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
function myFunction(variable){
    variable += 1;
}
```

I’m trying to make a/b increase, but it doesn’t have any effect. I think it is only changing a copy of the variable. Is it possible to fix this?

Edit: It doesn’t seem to work for `let`. Is it possible with `let` as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could treat those two variables as keys on the `window` object, and pass the name of the variable to your function:

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
function myFunction(variable){
    window[variable] += 1;
    console.log(a,b)
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "myFunction('a')">Increase A</button>
<button onclick = "myFunction('b')">Increase B</button>
```

Though it may be better to use your own object container instead of depending on `window`:

```js
var myData = {a: 0, b: 0};

function myFunction(variable){
    myData[variable] += 1;
    console.log(myData.a, myData.b)
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "myFunction('a')">Increase A</button>
<button onclick = "myFunction('b')">Increase B</button>
```

...or, indeed, to not depend on global variables at all, depending on what you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, non-object arguments are passed in by value, so what you're doing here is passing in the value of `a` and `b`, not a reference to the variable themselves.  Instead, you can refer to these variables by name, and access them on the `window` object, like this:

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(variable){
    window[variable] += 1;

    console.log(a, b)
}
```

HTML:

```html
<button onclick = "myFunction('a')">Increase A</button>
<button onclick = "myFunction('b')">Increase B</button>
```